# laravel blade append to @section in @forelse

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

My main template blade has a `@yield('section_name')` in the `<head>` tag to append css/ js.
Now I have a forelse like this:

```
@forelse($collection as $item)
    some text
    @section('section_name')
        // link to stylesheet
    @endsection
@empty
 // something went wrong
@endforelse
```

When this loops for like 5 times, only one stylesheet is added. After that, it seems like the @yield is not working anymore. Is there a way to make this work so I can keep appending items to that section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @append instead of @endsection

```
@forelse($collection as $item)
    some text
    @section('section_name')
        // link to stylesheet
    @append
@empty
 // something went wrong
@endforelse
```

Comment: Ah thanks! That worked! Where did you find that? I couldn't find it in the laravel documentation. Is there another documentation for these kind of things?

Comment: Blade documentation.